# Gaussian plume model

Tags: geoprocessing, spatial-statistics, gaussian-plume

I'm looking for code to implement a Gaussian plume model in 3D.  Any suggestions on where to start? Are there any python scripts out there?

Comment: *Which* Gaussian plume model?  There are zillions.  And what format/software do you need?

Comment: I'm looking for a gaussian plume model for atmospheric dispersion. I am using ArcScene, and I need it in 3 dimensions (x,y,z). I'd like to mimic this http://ready.arl.noaa.gov/READY_gaussian.php, but in 3D.

Answer (score 1):

You might check with John Tauxe to see if anyone has ported his [ShowFlow2](http://showflow.tauxe.net/) to python.

Answer (score 1):

There is a freely available Matlab implementation of 3D Gaussian plume. Google for 'gaussianPlume'. Currently, the link is http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13279-gaussianplume.